# Identify the occurence of value after another specific value

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have the following table:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| ID |    Date    | Variable |
+----+------------+----------+
| a  | 12/03/2017 | d        |
| a  | 15/04/2017 | d        |
| a  | 20/06/2017 | c        |
| b  | 14/05/2017 | c        |
| b  | 15/08/2017 | c        |
| b  | 16/09/2017 | c        |
+----+------------+----------+
```

For each ID, I'd like to have a check in the separate column which tells whether there was a "c" value after the occurence of "d" value, like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| ID |    Date    | Variable | Check |    Date    |
+----+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| a  | 12/03/2017 | d        |     1 | 20/06/2017 |
| a  | 15/04/2017 | d        |     1 | 20/06/2017 |
| a  | 20/06/2017 | c        |     1 | 20/06/2017 |
| b  | 14/05/2017 | c        |     0 | 0          |
| b  | 15/08/2017 | c        |     0 | 0          |
| b  | 16/09/2017 | c        |     0 | 0          |
+----+------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

It's not just about finding the occurence of "c", but about seeing whether "c" occurs after d or not. It would also help to have the corresponding date in a separate column. I was trying with removing the duplicates & then identifying the lead value (or n of rows > 1), but is there a simpler way to do this?

Any dplyr or data.table approach would be most helpful.

Comment: Do you mean check for when c occurs after d as well as check for d itself? Because that's what your expected output looks like

Comment: Are there only `c` and `d` in the `Variable` column?

Comment: What if there are more than one `c` after `d`? Which date would you report to the second `Date` column?

Comment: Do you expect `Check` to be `1` in 3rd row?

Comment: @heds1, I mean only check for c when d occured previously.

Comment: @www, yes, in principle we could say there are only c and d. As for the dates, I would report the date of the 1st occurence of c.

Comment: @MKR, no, actually this is not a condition, it may be or not.

Comment: lead or lag via `data.table::lead` will be your best friend here I guess. It shifts a column by n rows and then you can compare each row (d == c => 1)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr). There must be a better way than this, but I think this should work. `unique(Variable[!is.na(Variable)])` is to get a vector with only `c("c", "d")`, `c("d", "c")`, `"c"`, or `"d"`. If you are sure there are no `NA`, you can remove `!is.na`. `Date[Variable %in% "c"][1]` is to select the first date.

```
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Check = ifelse(identical(unique(Variable[!is.na(Variable)]), c("d", "c")), 
                        1L, 0L)) %>%
  mutate(Date2 = ifelse(Check == 1L, Date[Variable %in% "c"][1], "0")) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   ID    Date       Variable Check Date2     
#   <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <int> <chr>     
# 1 a     12/03/2017 d            1 20/06/2017
# 2 a     15/04/2017 d            1 20/06/2017
# 3 a     20/06/2017 c            1 20/06/2017
# 4 b     14/05/2017 c            0 0         
# 5 b     15/08/2017 c            0 0         
# 6 b     16/09/2017 c            0 0
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID Date Variable
a  '12/03/2017' d
a  '15/04/2017' d
a  '20/06/2017' c
b  '14/05/2017' c
b  '15/08/2017' c
b  '16/09/2017' c",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution. Also suggested by @RYoda, you can use `data.table::shift` to test for your condition and then merge the results back to the original dataset

```
check <- dat[, {
       idx <- Variable =='d' & shift(Variable, type="lead") == "c"
       list(MatchDate=ifelse(any(idx), shift(Date, type="lead", fill=NA_character_)[idx][1L], "0"), 
           Check=as.integer(any(idx)))
    }, by=.(ID)]   
dat[check, on=.(ID)]

#    ID       Date Variable  MatchDate Check
# 1:  a 12/03/2017        d 20/06/2017     1
# 2:  a 15/04/2017        d 20/06/2017     1
# 3:  a 20/06/2017        c 20/06/2017     1
# 4:  b 14/05/2017        c          0     0
# 5:  b 15/08/2017        c          0     0
# 6:  b 16/09/2017        c          0     0
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(ID=rep(c('a','b'), each=3),
    Date=c("12/03/2017","15/04/2017","20/06/2017","14/05/2017","15/08/2017","16/09/2017"),
    Variable=c('d','d','c','c','c','c'))
```

Comment: Same basic idea: `dat[, chk := setDT(shift(Variable, 0:1))[.("c", "d"), on=.(V1,V2), .N, nomatch=0] > 0, by=ID]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful, and I hesitated between your answer and the one from @www, but since I would need it for educational purposes, I've decided to go with dplyr (usually easier to understand for R beginners).

Comment: no problem! maybe a good research project would be to get them to compare `tidyverse` and `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be arrived using `fill` from `tidyr` package. The approach is as:
First populate `Check` and `C_Date` for rows with `Variable` as `c`. Then fill up the rows above using `fill` function on both `Check` and `C_Date` columns. This steps will populate desired values in rows with `d` value. Finally, just replace the value of `Check` and `C_Date` for rows having `Variable` as `c`.

Note: OP suggested that `Check` for rows with `Variable` as `c` can be either `0` or `1`. My solution has considered it to be `0`.

```
# Data
df <- read.table(text = "ID     Date  Variable
a  12/03/2017 d
a  15/04/2017 d    
a  20/06/2017 c
b  14/05/2017 c
b  15/08/2017 c
b  16/09/2017 c", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)   


df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(ID, Date) %>%
  mutate(Check = ifelse(Variable == "c", 1L, NA),
         c_Date = ifelse(Variable == "c", as.character(Date), NA) ) %>%
  fill(Check, .direction = "up") %>%
  fill(c_Date, .direction = "up") %>%
  mutate(Check = ifelse(Variable == "c", 0L, Check),
         c_Date = ifelse(Variable == "c", NA, c_Date) )


# Result
#      ID    Date                Variable Check c_Date    
#      <chr> <dttm>              <chr>    <int> <chr>     
#    1 a     2017-03-12 00:00:00 d            1 2017-06-20
#    2 a     2017-04-15 00:00:00 d            1 2017-06-20
#    3 a     2017-06-20 00:00:00 c            0 <NA>      
#    4 b     2017-05-14 00:00:00 c            0 <NA>      
#    5 b     2017-08-15 00:00:00 c            0 <NA>      
#    6 b     2017-09-16 00:00:00 c            0 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks - works & reads very well, however I might need it for larger datasets, and there my experience with tidyr's fill is that it might be quite slow.

Comment: @Psych91 You are absolutely right about `fill` but I choose it to provide flexibility with multiple occurrence/re-occurrence  of  `c` and `d` the `C_Date` will be from the 1st occurrence of `c` after `d`.